# nginx: simplify config for force ssl on specific path for rails app

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, configuration, unicorn

im using the config below. it works, but the problem for me is the repeating of some lines.
the `proxy_*` directives need to be in `location /admin` also, because only one `location` will be executed by nginx per request. 
what options do i have to remove this duplicate code without extracting it in new files and include it afterwards?

is there an option to tell nginx do continue with `location @rails` after `location /admin` was selected and processed?

ah and btw, what is the difference between `location @rails` and `location /`?

```
server {
  ...
  location /admin {
    include /etc/nginx/force_ssl;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails;

  }

  location @rails {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://rails;
  }
...
}
```

/etc/nginx/force_ssl:

```
if ( $scheme = "http" ) {
  rewrite  ^/(.*)$  https://$host/$1 permanent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are asking multiple questions.

---

Regarding the first question, how to get rid of redundancy:

In general you can move any part of the config file into a separate file and then use the `include` directive to include it once or multiple times. [include directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include)

---

Second question regarding redirecting from one location to the other:

Using the `rewrite` directive you can call one location from another. Internally Nginx will create a second request to handle the called location, but the user doesn't see anything of that. With the keyword `last` after the rewrite destination you tell Nginx to stop processing rules at this point and select the next location based on the current content of `$uri`, this variable contains the result of all the already executed rewrites. So for example if you just want to redirect everything to `@rails` you could use a rule like this to rewrite any url into `@rails` and then the `last` tells Nginx to look for a location with the name `@rails`:

```
rewrite . @rails last;
```

Details are described here: [rewrite module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html)

---

In your third question you ask if there is any difference between the two locations `@rails` and `/admin`:

I cannot tell you based on the snipped that you posted. I only see that `/admin` includes one more file than `@rails`. So the answer to this question depends on your backend app and the context of the rest of the Nginx configuration.

Comment: thank you, the rewrite seems to be the best solution for me, ill check this out! meanwhile to the third question: i asked whats the difference between `location @rails` and `location /` (root, not /admin!). i can replace @rails with / with no obvious changes in the behavior of the webserver...

Comment: I cannot definitely answer the question regarding the difference between `/` and `@rails` because it depends on two factors: 1. How your backend application handles the rewritten requests 2. The rest of you Nginx conf that you didn't post. If for example your `location /` does nothing else than call `@rails` it's very possible that you could as well just drop `location /` and rename `@rails` into `/`, but that's only and example and I cannot guarantee anything.

Comment: ok, i have replaced the `proxy_*` directives with `rewrite . @reils last;` in `location /admin` now. it redirects me to https now but it does not query the @rails app. the output remains blank white. :(

Comment: Sorry, I can't remotely debug your app, Stack Exchange is meant for precise questions that can be answered based on the information provided.